# Select aggregations based on sub aggregation results doc count

Tags: elasticsearch

I am aiming to only select those aggregations that have min_doc_count match defined  in sub aggregations. Not sure if it is possible. 
Basically I want to select only those buckets that have propertyid belonging to a particular import.
Here is my query.

```
GET properties/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "Agency_Id": [
        "16"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "property_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "PropertyId",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "import_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Import_Id": "90040"
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "import_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Import_Id",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "size": 10000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual result

```
{
  "took" : 16,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1163,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "property_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "011162330",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : 90040,
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "6065590",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : 90040,
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "6289352",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : 90040,
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "gd-00-022386",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [ ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected

```
{
  "took" : 16,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1163,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "property_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "011162330",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : 90040,
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "6065590",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : 90040,
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "6289352",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "import_filter" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "import_id" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : 90040,
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and explain the exact result you expect? It's not clear on what you want to filter? propertyId? min_doc_count? import?

Comment: @Val Have added actual and expected results Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your query, you need [Bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) 
Query:

```
GET properties/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "Agency_Id": [
        "16"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "property_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "PropertyId",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "import_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Import_Id": "90040"
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "import_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Import_Id",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "size": 10000
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "mybucket_selector": { ---> select product bucket if import bucket has any value
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "FinalCount": "import_filter>import_id._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.FinalCount>0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks this work! Is it possible to simply select import_filter.doc_count>0 based on import filter aggregation only -trying to remove import_id aggregation as it looks redundant?

Comment: Glad could be of help.You will need to  replace import_id with value count aggregation.

Comment: "FinalCount": "import_filter._count" seems to do the trick. Thanks again!